# NPM hangs when attempting to install packages "loadRequestedDeps → netwo"

Tags: npm

Hello npm hangs on me when installing any package, I have attempted the proxy config fix but no success. NPM 3.3.9, OSX el cap, node v4.2.2. https://slack-files.com/T03AJT6G5-F0EE622BW-6fbdd19cbe

Comment: maybe you can try to use npm install --verbose for see what is happening, if you no see any error maybe the package is very large and have many dependencies and take some time for donwload it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your package.json has right permissions or run as administrator => `sudo npm install`

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 doug doug  604 Jun  9 09:50 package.json
```

My case user don't have permissions to write on package.json and cause this error.